# NearestNeighbors testing

Tags: classification, data, bigdata, cosine-distance

I have used

```
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(metric= 'cosine', algorithm='brute').fit(items_features)

distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(item_features)
```

to find some suggested items based on some attributes in the dataset.
I really find the suggested items but I need to see if these items are really the more nearest items.

I tried this function to find the similarity between distances of A with each items  B or C or D
spatial.distance.cosine(distances of A,distances of B/C/D)

One output for my code is

```
B with 0.0004864387565900463
C with 0.003675794744087746
D with 0.05855020953442236
E with 0.0048087457894999686
```

I thought the items must be orderd from the neighrest but E is break the rule.
Is those distances in above is logic or there is a wrong.

How can I make sure my algorithm work well???